# ORA-00904: "TOOL_WEBPAGE"."ID": invalid identifier

Tags: python, django, reactjs, oracle

I have a preexisting database which I am trying to access. I have already ran the command

```
python manage.py makemigrations dashboard
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate
```

However, I am getting an error when trying to migrate:

> Unable to create the django_migrations table (ORA-2000: missing ALWAYS keyword)

Answer (score 0):

(Just a side note: there's no `ORA-2000`; `ORA-02000` is its error code).

---

Error you got sounds as if you are trying to create a table which uses an identity column. However, database version doesn't support it. As identity columns were introduced in 12c, you're probably using 11g or lower.

```
SQL> select * From v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> create table test
  2    (id number generated by default on null as identity);
  (id number generated by default on null as identity)
                       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword


SQL>
```

What to do? Either use a higher database version, or don't try to create an identity column. If you choose the second option, in those "lower" database versions the same effect ("autoincrementing") was achieved by a sequence and a database trigger.

---

Finally: how are question title and question text related? Title says that there's an invalid identifier. If that bothers you as well, that error usually means that you're referencing a column (`ID`) in a table (`TOOL_WEBPAGE`), but - there's no such a column in that table. Hint is: letter case (lower? Mixed? Should be uppercase).

Comment: I'm a little confused because I didn't create an identity column

Comment: Maybe you didn't, manually, but - maybe tool you use did (the one that tried to create the `django_migrations` table, but failed).

Comment: Interesting, whenever I did makemigrations, it did create a 0001_initial.py which created an 'id' increment but I thought I deleted that line